# Pulse audio does not play sound

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

I was using pulse audio on opensuse tumbleweed , then I connected a hdmi to a monitor, but then the audio suddenly stops (the analog one), then disconnected the cable but there is no sound  and when trying to enter to pavucontrol it says
[image]

and when trying the comand showed here
it says
Continuous failure: connection refused
pa_context_connect () failed: connection refused

as well when entering pulse audio manager
there is no connection or sinks or sources
[image]

Comment: First, try rebooting. And fix the typos in your post; there are many.

Comment: Do a `ps axu | grep pulse` to check if the Pulseaudio server is running, try to reproduce the problem (follow the same steps), and if the same thing happens again, check if the server is still running. If not, it crashed for some reason, so the next step is to figure out why that happened.